# get method erases all nodes?

Tags: firebase, delphi, firebase-realtime-database, firemonkey

i trying to use [FB4D](https://github.com/SchneiderInfosystems/FB4D) in my delphi app.

but whenever i try to use `Get` method it erases all nodes and writes timestamp in database.

this is the code i am using:

```
// Clicking on btnLogin
procedure TForm3.BtnLoginClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not Assigned(fConfig) then
    fConfig := TFirebaseConfiguration.Create(cApiKey, cId);
  fConfig.Auth.SignInWithEmailAndPassword(Edit1.Text, Edit2.Text,
    onUserResponse, onError);
end; 

//Log In Success
procedure TForm3.onUserResponse(const Info: string; user: IFirebaseUser);
begin
  UID := user.UID;
  pass := Edit2.Text;
  Email := user.Email;
  fConfig.RealTimeDB.GetServerVariables(cServerVariableTimeStamp, GetRTDBPath,
    onServerStamp, onError);
  Text1.Text := UID;
end; 

//Getting ServerTime for Usage
procedure TForm3.onServerStamp(const ServerVar: string; Val: TJSONValue);
var
  ST: int64;
begin
  ST := StrToInt64(Val.Value);
  sDate := TTimeZone.Local.ToLocalTime(UnixToDateTime(ST div 1000));
  SaveUser;
  UpdateLoginStatus;
end; 

//Trying to get data to use but is not getting at all 
procedure TForm3.UpdateLoginStatus;
begin
  fConfig.RealTimeDB.Get(GetRTDBPath, onGetResponse, onError);
end; 

//updating LoggedIn Status
procedure TForm3.onGetResponse(ResourceParams: TRequestResourceParam;
  Val: TJSONValue);
var
  sValue: TJSONObject;
begin
  ShowRTNode(ResourceParams, Val);

  //Below Will be used later once data is received 
  {sValue := TJSONObject.Create;
  try
    sValue.AddPair('LoggedIn', 'True');
    fConfig.RealTimeDB.Patch(GetRTDBPath, sValue, ShowRTNode, onError);
  finally
    sValue.Free;
  end;}
end;
```

can't use Update Data as when i try to get Data it deletes all the nodes and then creates a timestamp in path.

Why so ?

Answer (score 1):

> This is a side effect of RealTimeDB.GetServerVariables(cServerVariableTimeStamp, GetRTDBPath..). This function does not return the time stamp only. It writes the time stamp also in the node addressed by ResourceParams. Please read also the description in the wiki here:
>   https://github.com/SchneiderInfosystems/FB4D/wiki/FB4D-Reference-IRealTimeDB#get-a-server-variable

Solution is use custom `timestamp` node in database and you're ready to go.

Comment: Correct answered ;)